# Mysql Insert unique record in table having one to many relation

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, inner-join

[image]I have two table twpcu_posts and twpcu_postmeta having one to many relationship. Table twpcu_postmeta has column post_id, meta_key, meta_value. post_id is the foreign key in twpcu_postmeta .

twpcu_posts   twpcu_postmeta
id  name      id  post_id   meta_key   meta_value
1   hhh       1    1        ky_hello   hello
2    1        ky_morning hello1
3    -         -          -
Now I want to add _wpbdp[fields][55] as meta_key and EMAIL as meta_value against post_id 1. How to do that ? I have around 1000 records in twpcu_posts having one to many relationship with twpcu_postmeta and want to add same meta_key and value for each id of twpcu_posts table.

I tried the below query but it rather updated all the record against id 1 to meta_key '_wpbdp[fields][55] and meta_value EMAIL.

```sql
UPDATE `twpcu_postmeta` pm inner join twpcu_posts ps ON pm.post_id= ps.id 
SET pm.meta_key = '_wpbdp[fields][55]', pm.meta_value = 'EMAIL' 
WHERE ps.post_status = 'publish' AND ps.post_type = 'wpbdp_listing'
```

Thanks,
In the image you can see after running query it updated all the records against id 49397 instead of inserting single row

Comment: An INSERT not an update an where does wp_posts com into it this table is not mentioned in your query or question.AND please post what you want twpcu_postmeta to look like after this process..

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do exactly. Do you want to add a new row in `twpcu_postmeta ` for every different `wp_post`, or just a single row, for the `wp_post` with `id = 1` ? And in both cases, as mentioned by @P.Salmon, you will need an `INSERT`, not `UPDATE`.

Comment: yes exactly I need to insert just one row against every id from twpcu_posts

Comment: I dont know how joins works for insertion any help would be appreciated

Comment: Then what you need is a `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` query ([like this](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp)), but in your case, the `SELECT` subquery will also use a `JOIN`. You can start by writing a `SELECT .. JOIN` that gives you the rows you want to insert, and then add the `INSERT` part on top :)

Comment: I don't see where joins come into it you appear to only want to insert from one table to another.